# how to display logo and text side to side in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display text side to logo, with the below code I am able to display in next line after the logo. I've tried searching on this issue but I'm still not getting what my problem is. I am using bootstrap 3.3.7v.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-
            toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
           <span><img src="images/logo.png" height="100" alt="logo" /></span>
           <h2>MyWebiste</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you add your css code?

Comment: Set your `h2` to `display: inline-block`

Comment: @demogorgon.net, I am using bootstrap 3.3.7v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a container around the logo and the text, than defined it as a flexbox with vertical alignment.

```css
.nav-logo {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <span> <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" height="100" alt="logo" />
 </span>
        <h2>MyWebiste</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks it's worked, can you please tell me how to display caption to MyWebiste.   Ex:            MyWebiste                                                                            
                                                sometext

Comment: You can use the caption tag https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_caption.asp

Comment: I tried setting caption to webiste name, but they are not working

Answer (score 1):

just add this to your local `css` file

```
.nav-logo h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution for web responsive